# Not a valid member of a model [Help]

Tags: lua, roblox

So, im creating a button script, when clicked, if a certain condition is true, it finds all of the children of a different model, but when i find the children, it gives me an error saying "Obj is not a valid member of model" and then doesnt do anything

Here is my code:

```
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if(hit.Name == "RightFoot" or hit.Name == "LeftFoot") then
        if(script.Parent.Color == Color3.fromRGB(0, 255, 0)) then
            --This line is where im getting problems, when i do this :GetChildren
            for _, object in pairs(script.Parent.Parent.Obj:GetChildren()) do 
                if(object:IsA("BasePart")) then
                    object.CanCollide = true
                    object.Transparency = 0
                end
            end
        end
    end
end)
```

Comment: try :waitforchild instead of obj and have obj in  quotes like this: script.Parent.Parent:WaitForChild("Obj"):GetChildren()) do

Answer (score -1):

`<something> is not a valid member of model` is is the error you get when you try to access a value that doesn't exist. So whatever `script.Parent.Parent` is, it does not have a child called `Obj`.

Instead of navigating to the object using a relative path like script.Parent.Parent, I would recommend using an absolute path from somewhere reliable. Something like ...

```
local button = script.Parent

button.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
if(hit.Name == "RightFoot" or hit.Name == "LeftFoot") then

    -- find the model you are looking for
    local targetModel = game.workspace:FindFirstChild("Obj", true)
    if not targetModel then
        warn("could not find Obj in the workspace, try looking somewhere else")
        return
    end

    -- if the button is green, make stuff invisible
    if(button.Color == Color3.fromRGB(0, 255, 0)) then
        for _, object in pairs(targetModel:GetChildren()) do 
            if(object:IsA("BasePart")) then
                object.CanCollide = true
                object.Transparency = 0
            end
        end
    end
end
```

end)

Comment: Searching from Workspace prevents you from having multiple copies of this model. It also risks a collision with a player-controlled name (a character, a hat, or maybe something with a name chosen by the player, like a humanoid).

Comment: That's a very good point, I was trying to suggest some kind of absolute path, but I guess game.workspace is too general. Especially because I'm also not sure where this button script exists in the workspace.